# Проблема с @connect декораторами в react-redux

Tags: javascript, babel, reactjs

для старта react-приложения использую стандартный create-react-app от фейсбука.

Однако, когда пытаюсь применить декоратор @connect из библиотеки react-redux, возникает ошибка

```
Syntax error: Unexpected token
@connect( state => ({}))
^
```

Пробовала действовать по инструкции отсюда: [babel](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=false&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-0&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code=%40annotation%0Aclass%20MyClass%20%7B%20%7D%0A%0Afunction%20annotation(target)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20target.annotated%20%3D%20true%3B%0A%7D%0A)

вот мой файл .babelrc

```
{
  "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy"]
}
```

как сделать так, чтобы корректно заработали декораторы? 
или может быть есть какой-то аналог create-react-app для редакс, чтобы декораторы работали "из коробки"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Менее варварский способ, который исключает блуждание по конфигам react-create-app:

Добавляем пакеты:

```
yarn add babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy
yarn add core-decorators
yarn add babel-preset-stage-1
yarn add babel-preset-es2015
```

файл .babelrc можно оставить такой же как и в предыдущем ответе:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react", "stage-1"],
  "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy"]
}
```

Для того, чтобы продолжить свои эксперименты над сборкой найдите в package.json следующий раздел:

```
  "scripts": {
      "start": "react-scripts start",
      "build": "react-scripts build",
      "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
      "eject": "react-scripts eject"
   }
```

Запустите

```
npm run eject
```

Это позволяет "вытащить" конфигурации webpack в отдельную директорию config

Answer (score 1):

За ночь получилось разобраться благодаря вот этой статье: [настройка декораторов в babel](http://technologyadvice.github.io/es7-decorators-babel6/) и [quick-fix decorators at create-react-app](http://bjeld.com/tips/quick-fix-for-enabling-decorators-with-create-react-app-without-ejecting/)

```
npm i -S babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy
```

файл .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react", "stage-1"],
  "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy"]
}
```

в фейсбуковской сборке creaate-react-app сборщик webpack находится внутри node_modules/react-scripts:

```
node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.dev.js
node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.prod.js
```

дописать необходимые плагины в loaders[]:

```
{
    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
    include: paths.appSrc,
    loader: 'babel',
    query: {
      // тут могут быть другие Ваши настройки
      babelrc: false,
      presets: [require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app')],
      cacheDirectory: true,
      // добавляем плагины:
      plugins: [
        'transform-runtime',
        'transform-decorators-legacy',
      ],
    }
  },
```

Comment: Все так. Дело в пресетах. Декораторы не стандартизированы в `es2015`, поэтому необходимо подключать как минимум `stage-1`. Можно даже `stage-0`.

Comment: вы правите конфиги create-react-app? этого нельзя делать